# Is traveling by train in the night in Morocco safe?

Tags: trains, safety, morocco, marrakech

Is traveling by train safe during the night in Morocco?

I would like to take a night train from Marrakech to Fes or Rabat, to save a holiday day. Do you think it is wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only anecdotal, as I travelled by bus in Morocco, but I met many other backpackers who did travel by train and they didn't report any problems. As I answered to a previous question, [Morocco is generally a very safe country to travel in](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5962/family-with-kids-driving-from-marrakesh-to-fez-any-threat-of-danger-for-daytim). [Seat61's entry on Morocco](http://www.seat61.com/Morocco.htm) doesn't give any warnings - and the trains look quite comfy too!

Answer (score 3):

We did a few overnight trips in Morocco around 2005, generally it was fine.

But on our last trip from Marrakech to Tangier someone's wallet and travel documents were stolen. It was 6 people from our group, filling up the whole cabin, the bag hung up above their head, on the far end from the door. Still somehow they managed to get it.

So I would recommend keeping your important personal belongings **very close** but I think it's common sense in most countries.

Other than this we didn't have any other bad experience, travelling on the train was quite nice, the cars have air conditioning and people were friendly.